# Help me find Frost, skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Where can I find Frost, when I lost him? I last remember leaving him at Riften Stables, 8-9 days later I went back there and he was gone! So he isn't there, like I had so much weight on me I was at Hog Rock Redoubt near Markarth and I headed to Whiterun Stables and bought a horse and wanted to see if Frost was at Riften Stables - he wasn't. So can anyone please help me find Frost?